# Weighted least squares with measurment errors: how to get proper standard errors for coefficients?

Tags: r, measurement-error, weighted-regression

If we have outcome variable as measurements with associated SD as form of measurement uncertainty and we want to incorporate the uncertainty information in linear regression model, what is the proper way in doing so? One approach to dealing with similar situations is weighted least squares, which can account for non-homogenous variance. However, in its canonic formulation, WLS considers just relative scaling of variances and I think this can lead to inappropriate standard errors of coefficients.

Indeed, one would argue that higher absolute uncertainty of outcome values should be reflected in higher uncertainty of regression coefficients.

Is there some simple way to adjust regression fit with WLS in R, so that it treats the weights in absolute sense (that is, not as undimensional relative proportion), so that it yields correct standard errors of coefficient? Or some another way to deal with the situation in R (I know how to solve the problem in bayesian way, but there must be some simple adjustment in frequentist framework for such situations as well).

**EDIT:**  I think the options varIdent or varFixed from nlme package might be useful, but I have not yet fully understood how they work due to lack of sufficient familiarity with nlme. I do not know if they work just as some scale of variance or can be used to represent predefined variances for individual outcomes.